# setting form to $valid in angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, unit-testing

I have a directive that I am to test for form validation that is set as an attribute.

```
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
```

The form name is given off of the element attr

```
 $scope.theFormName = elem.attr('name');
```

Where I need to get inside of is the **if statement**

```
if ($scope.theForm.$valid) {
```

Inside of my beforeEach for my unit test I have

```
html = angular.element("<div ha-form-validation name=\"name\" class=\"ng-invalid\"></div>");
    $rootScope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = $compile(html)($rootScope);

    $rootScope.$digest(element);

    scope = element.scope();

    scope.name = {
        name: "test",
    };
```

I have tried to set the form as valid in my test

```
    var form = scope.theFormName.$setValidity("properties", true);
```

However **theFormName** is returning undefined

```
 scope.theFormName.$valid  = undefined
```

Is there a way to set this as valid?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here:

1. The element (`html`) you are compiling doesn't have a `form` element enclosing it that could be set to valid.
2. You should try adding properties to the `$scope` before compiling `html` like this:

   ```
   var scope = $rootScope.$new();
   scope.name = {
       name: "test"
   };
   element = $compile(html)(scope);

   scope.$digest();
   ```
3. I'm not sure exactly what your directive looks like, but if you are trying to access the `form` that encloses it, then you can do that using:

   ```
   require: '^form',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl)
   ```

   The angular [`FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) on the parent form will get injected into `link` as the 4th argument (`formCtrl`), rather than having to pass the name of the form in as an attribute on the element.

Also, if you're trying to do some kind of custom validation with `ha-form-validation`, [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) might help.